# How to pass a php array of string values to a javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I need to use php arrays in my javascript code. The arrays are defined in PHP in the same file as the javascript.

I have tried the following two ways:

```
var array_name = new Array('<?php echo implode("','", $php_array);?>');
```

and

```
var array_name = <?php echo json_encode($php_array);?>;
```

This works great if my php arrays are integers. However, when I try to do either when the array is a list of strings, then it does not work.

Any suggestions on what other options I have?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP to Javascript Array (Kind of)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968977/php-to-javascript-array-kind-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put that json string into quotes (single quotes!)

```
var array_name = '<?php echo json_encode($php_array);?>';
```

enjooy

Comment: Thanks! As I went to enter the quotes in, I found my mistake; I forgot an '='. I've also discovered that it works both ways--quotes or not.

Comment: @Marina: yes but with your one it's not json but class javascript array :)