# How to pass a PHP array to JS and generate a JS array

Tags: php, javascript

```
$allVal =  array(array(123, 0), array(345, 1), array(456, 2));
```

Code at above is an PHP array, currently I would like to pass this array to javascript and the output in Javascript should look like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var d = [[123, 0], [345, 1], [456, 2]];
</script>
```

BTW: PHP code and Js code in the same page.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a php array of string values to a javascript variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905220/how-to-pass-a-php-array-of-string-values-to-a-javascript-variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://fr.php.net/json_encode) should be able to help you

```
<?php
$allVal =  array(array(123, 0), array(345, 1), array(456, 2));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php echo 'var d = ' . json_encode($allVal) . ';'; ?>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's json_encode method to convert an array into a javascript oject prior to sending it back to the client side. See

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

--Inline
Use a line similar to

```
<?php echo "var = ". json_encode($myArray); ?>
```

--Asynchronous
A line similar to

```
<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>
```

One thing you will have to take into consideration is that you'll need to pass a header to the server stating that you expect the response format to be json.