# Assigning a php array into a javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to assign a PHP array into a javascript variable like this:

```
var jsArray = <?php echo $phpArray; ?>;
```

But it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP to Javascript Array (Kind of)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968977/php-to-javascript-array-kind-of) - There are even more duplicates of your question. Please use the search first and see as well the Related column on the right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try to use JSON

```
var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
```

accessible then via

```
jsArray.someKey
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/9e705)

Answer (score 3):

you can serialize array in php using json_encode and use it inside JS

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php
$series = array("name"=>"N51",
                "data"=>array(1024,
                              array("y"=>2048,
                                    "events"=>array("mouseOver"=>'function(){$reporting.html(\'description of value\');}')
                                   ),
                              4096)
               );
json_encode($series);
?>
```

The above code outputs:

```
{"name":"N51","data":[1024,{"y":2048,"events":{"mouseOver":"function(){$reporting.html('description of value');}"}},4096]}
```