# Convert array from php to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

How do i take a php array

```
$arr = (('date'=>'03-22-2012', 'count'=>1000 ), ('date'=>'03-23-2011', 'count'=>1170 ));
```

and convert it to:

```
var arr = [['03-22-2012', 1000], ['03-23-2011', 1170]]
```

usable by a javascript function?

is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning a php array into a javascript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167620/assigning-a-php-array-into-a-javascript-array)

Comment: that is pretty easy to convert ... do you want to use it via AJAX ??  or you just want to convert PHP array to comparable JavaScript array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: i actually need it in the exact format I posted so not in json format no keys no curly braces ...is there an easy way to get this? Thanks!!

Comment: It just means you need to transform your php array before `json_encode`ing it.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for json_encode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Only your php array definition looks a bit strange :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
    array('03-22-2012', 1000 ),
    array('03-23-2011', 1170 )
);

echo "var = ".json_encode($arr).";";
```

Output

```
var = [["03-22-2012",1000],["03-23-2011",1170]];
```