# php array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (including escaping newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines)

I have a PHP array that I want to use in a javascript script.  I suppose that I will have to convert it to a string that can be understood by javascript, and embed the string inside the script.  What is the best way to accomplish this.

EDIT - This is for initial load of the page, not subsequent AJAX call

```
$textMessages = array();
```

Comment: See 1st answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968977/php-to-javascript-array-kind-of

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the server side and `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` on the client side. Both client side functions are natively built-into modern browsers but if you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Answer (score 1):

[json_encode()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Put in a PHP array, receive a string representation of a JS array.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is perfect for this.

`echo json_encode($textMessages);`